# How to merge several list of arrays based on first element?

Tags: java, arrays

I have several lists of string arrays. I would like to merge this lists in a single one based on the first element of each array.

Basically, I would like to merge this two list

```
ArrayList<String[]> list1 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
list1.add(new String[]{"key1","a","a","a"});
list1.add(new String[]{"key2","a","a","a"});
list1.add(new String[]{"key4","a","a","a"});

ArrayList<String[]> list2 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
list2.add(new String[]{"key1","b","b"});
list2.add(new String[]{"key2","b","b"});
list2.add(new String[]{"key3","c","c"});
```

in this one

```
[key4,a,a,a,null,null]
[key3,null,null,null,c,c]
[key2,a,a,a,b,b]
[key1,a,a,a,b,b]
```

Some more things :

- List order does not matter
- Array order is **important**, so I have to add padding if value not present

Does someone know an efficient way to do it ?

**My current approach**

My current approach use an HashMap to store the key (first element of the array)

```
HashMap<String, String[]> results = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
process(list1); 
process(list2); 

void process(ArrayList<String[]> list) {
    for(String[]s : list) {
        if(!results.containsKey(s[0])) {
            results.put(s[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(s, 1, s.length));
        } else {
            String[] current = results.get(s[0]);
            results.put(s[0], concat(current, Arrays.copyOfRange(s, 1, s.length)));
        }
    }
}
```

which give me the ouput (incorrect because no "padding")

```
key4 [a, a, a]
key3 [c, c]
key2 [a, a, a, b, b]
key1 [a, a, a, b, b]
```

Comment: Do all the arrays always have the same length within list 1 and 2?

Comment: Inside the same list, arrays have the same length. But arrays in list1 and list2 can have different size.

Comment: And can list 2 contain a key that is *not* present in list 1 also?

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you need to do, is check `list2` if the desired key exists. If it does, simply merge the arrays. However, if the key is not present in `list2`, you have to add a padded array. This can be done relatively easy by returning a new array with the desired length.

Have a look at my code below:

```
public void mergeArrays() {

  ArrayList<String[]> list1 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  list1.add(new String[] { "key1", "a", "a", "a" });
  list1.add(new String[] { "key2", "a", "a", "a" });
  list1.add(new String[] { "key4", "a", "a", "a" });

  ArrayList<String[]> list2 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  list2.add(new String[] { "key1", "b", "b" });
  list2.add(new String[] { "key2", "b", "b" });
  list2.add(new String[] { "key3", "c", "c" });

  ArrayList<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();

  // Merge list1 to list2
  for (String[] array1: list1) {
     // Find key from list1 in list2
     int index = this.findIndex(array1[0], list2);

     // Key was found, merge arrays
     if (index > -1) {
        result.add(this.concat(array1, list2.get(index)));
     }
     // Key was not found, use padding
     else {
        // Padding second array with null values
        result.add(this.concat(array1, this.padding(list2.get(0).length, null)));
     }
  }

  // Merge list2 to list1
  for (String[] array2: list2) {
     // Find key from list2 in list1
     int index = this.findIndex(array2[0], list1);

     // Key was not found, use padding
     if (index == -1) {
        // Padding first array with null values
        String[] temp = this.concat(this.padding(list1.get(0).length, null), array2);
        temp[0] = array2[0]; // Set key
        result.add(temp);
     }
  }

  // Debug output
  for (String[] array: result) {
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println("");
  }
}

// Return array with padding
private String[] padding(final int size, final String padding) {
  String[] result = new String[size];
  Arrays.fill(result, padding);

  return result;
}

// Find needle in haystack and return index
private int findIndex(final String needle, final ArrayList<String[]> haystack) {
  for (int i = 0; i < haystack.size(); ++i) {
     if (haystack.get(i)[0].equals(needle)) {
        return i;
     }
  }

  return -1;
}

// Merge two arrays, omit first element of second array
private String[] concat(String[] arrayOne, String[] arrayTwo) {
  int arrayOneLength = arrayOne.length;
  int arrayTwoLength = arrayTwo.length;

  String[] result = new String[arrayOneLength + arrayTwoLength - 1];
  System.arraycopy(arrayOne, 0, result, 0, arrayOneLength);
  System.arraycopy(arrayTwo, 1, result, arrayOneLength, arrayTwoLength - 1); // Skip key in second array

  return result;
}
```

Output:

```
key1 a a a b b
key2 a a a b b
key4 a a a null null
key3 null null null c c
```

Comment: You can alter ``mergeArrays()`` such, that it returns the result and provides two arguments to pass in ``list1`` and ``list2``. Then you'll be able to call the method multiple times with different parameters and make it merge more than two lists.

Comment: I did it and it works fine. I just need to chained called to `mergeArrays` like this `mergeArrays(list1,mergeArrays(list2,list3))`. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant.